# Create an Array of objects in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list of objects in python. I'm doing this by making one object and appending it. Here is my code.

```
#Creating a Python object
class TestDat(object):
     Dat1 = None
     Dat2 = None
#Declaring the Test Array
TestArray = []
#Declaring the object
Test1 = TestDat()
#Defining the member variables in said object
Test1.Dat1 = 0
Test1.Dat1 = 1
#Appending the object to the List
TestArray.append(Test1)
#Rewriting and appending again
Test1.Dat1 = 3
Test1.Dat1 = 4
TestArray.append(Test1)
#Printing our Our Results
print TestArray[0].Dat1
print TestArray[1].Dat1
```

When I test it out. I get the output "4 4". This means that both elements of the list are the same. It seems like append is just copying a pointer to the object instead of a copy of said object. I would eventually like to do this in a loop so I can't be doing that. How can I get both elements of the List to be different without using a new object?

Comment: "How can I get both elements of the List to be different without using a new object?" You can't.

Comment: Essentially, you have TestArray = [Test1 obj, Test1 obj], so they are going to be the same.

Comment: "I'm trying to make a list of objects in python. I'm doing this by making one object" Why not try this by making multiple objects?

Answer (score 12):

There are several mistakes here:

First, you have inherited from "object" and there is no need to explicitly put it, you can leave it empty.

Second, **the way you declared your variables in your class** makes the class share the same values across all instances, thats why you get the latest modified values always. you should use "self.variable" instead, and declare a constructor function for that.

Third, **you are modifying Test1.Dat1 4 times and appending the same object twice.**
thats why you get the same object every time.

this is the right way:

```
class TestDat():          # leave this empty
    def __init__(self):   # constructor function using self
        self.Dat1 = None  # variable using self.
        self.Dat2 = None  # variable using self
    
TestArray = [] #empty array

Test1 = TestDat() #this is an object
Test2 = TestDat() #this is another object
        
Test1.Dat1 = 0 #assigning value to object 1 
Test1.Dat2 = 1 #assigning value to object 1 
    
Test2.Dat1 = 3 #assigning value to object 2 
Test2.Dat2 = 4 #assigning value to object 2

TestArray.append(Test1) #append object 1
TestArray.append(Test2) #append object 2 
    
print (TestArray[0].Dat1) # this is Test1
print (TestArray[1].Dat1) # this is Test2
```

or even simpler:

```
class TestDat():
    def __init__(self, Dat1, Dat2):
        self.Dat1 = Dat1
        self.Dat2 = Dat2

TestArray = [TestDat(0,1),
             TestDat(3,4)]

print (TestArray[0].Dat1) # this is Test1
print (TestArray[1].Dat1) # this is Test2
```

or this way:

```
class TestDat():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Dat1 = None
        self.Dat2 = None
    
TestArray = [] #empty array
size = 2       #number of loops

for x in range(size):  # appending empty objects
    TestArray.append(TestDat())

#initialize later
TestArray[0].Dat1 = 0
TestArray[0].Dat2 = 1

TestArray[1].Dat1 = 3
TestArray[1].Dat2 = 4

print("print everithing")
for x in range(len(TestArray)):
    print("object "+str(x))
    print(TestArray[x].Dat1)
    print(TestArray[x].Dat2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a list of objects in python. I'm doing this by making one object

You simply can't do this; your second statement contradicts your first statement. You must instantiate as many objects as you wish to have, end of story. Even if you try to use some kind of `copy` function, it is just creating a new instance for you under the hood.

What you can do is use a `for` loop to create your array.

```
testArray = []
for i in range(10):
    testDat = TestDat(dat1=i, dat2=i*2)
    testArray.append(testDat)
```

If you don't want to use a `for` loop, you can just instantiate a new instance before appending it to the array.

```
testArray = []
testDat = TestDat(dat1=1, dat2=2)
testArray.append(testDat)
testDat = TestDat(dat1=3, dat2=4) # re-assigns the variable to the new instance
testArray.append(testDat)
```

If you have an existing list of items from which you are creating this array of objects, the best thing you can do is use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build your new list. For instance, if you had an array of tuples:

```
myOriginalData = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
myNewList = [TestDat(dat1=x, dat2=y) for (x,y) in myOriginalData]
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right, when you add objects it does add them by reference.

There's a couple ways to do this. Probably the cleanest is just to make a new object for each entry. If you absolutely need to use the same instances with changed values, you can use `copy.copy`:

```
from copy import copy
...
# Set up object
TestArray.append(copy(test1))
# Change stuff
TestArray.append(copy(test2))
```

See: **https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html** for the differences between `copy` (aka shallow copy) and `deepcopy`, as it may be important depending on the complexity of your object. It also tells you how to implement `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` if copying the object is nontrivial.

So, TL;DR is I'd really suggest using new objects and discourage mutability, but `copy` is there if you need it.

Comment: Just as an amendment to my answer, `copy` and `deepcopy` do create new objects, but what I'm discouraging is depending on a mutable object  you're constantly changing as the source. There's some interesting discussion on immutability here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151733/if-immutable-objects-are-good-why-do-people-keep-creating-mutable-objects